# Setting scaladoc's output directory in SBT 0.13 (since docDirectory is deprecated)?

Tags: scala, sbt

It seems `docDirectory in Compile <<= (baseDirectory / "api")` is deprecated and sbt won't start if `build.sbt` contains the setting.

How should I set scaladoc's output directory in sbt **0.13**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following setting instead:

```
target in Compile in doc := baseDirectory.value / "api"
```

Comment: in 0.13 style that's `target in Compile in Doc := baseDirectory.value / "api"`

Comment: Seth: I keep forgetting about this; is there documentation somewhere showing the style changes introduced in 13?

Comment: @James See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html. In essence, use `.value` with `:=`, `+=` and `++=` and some other less-often-faced cases.